# Javascript searchbar with onkeyup event not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have here a search bar where I can search employee onkeyup event. But When i try to add class and another td tag then the function is not working. Please see my code below. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="imageindent">
      <img src="img.jpg" border="1" style="border-color:#CCCCCC" />
    </td>

    <td class="gentext" id="empname"> JOHN BRYAN SMITH <span class="textCapitalized"></span>
      <span class="textCapitalized">
        Gray<br />JohnSMith@gmail.com      <br />
      </span>
    </td>

    <td class="gentext"><span class="texblue">JUNIOR PRODUCER</span>/<br />EVENTS</td>
    <td width="120" class="title2">2114</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input name="search" type="text" class="textsimple" id="search2" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: That is because your function checks only the first cell of every row `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` you need to change that to some other cell because the first one contains an image.

Comment: @Titus Hi, May i know how can i do it? Sorry im just a newbie in javascript. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to search for matches in the second cell, use `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];`

Comment: @Titus Hi, tried it but its not showing anything. When i type the list is gone and didn't show anything. Thank you.

Comment: You have some invalid HTML `<em>/em>`, fix that an see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @Titus Hi I updated my code. But still not working. Please see updated code above. Thank you

Comment: @Titus But when i tried to simply put <td>Name of Employee</td> It's wokring but i need the class tag on my <td> table. Thank you

Comment: There is probably something else going on because I've tested it and it works https://jsbin.com/yipuweduke/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Titus I don't know why it's not working but when i tried to put plain <td> Name </td> in the first table row then set it to getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; it is working but i need those images

Comment: @titus it is now working. But another problem rise. SInce there is Display:none every time i search it added an empty td my list includes a hundred name so when i search the very last name it display in lower part of the screen because of the "Display:none" added on the empty td's.

Comment: You're hiding the row not the cell (`tr[i].style.display = "none";`) in the example code from your question.

Comment: @Titus Sorry wasn't able to realize that i need to actually hide the entire cell. Could you help me hide the entire cell? Thank you

Comment: @Titus tried to use visibility.hidden but then the result appear where it is before doing the search.

Comment: If you are using `tr[i].style.display = "none";` and still have spaces, you probably have some invalid HTML. I don't know what the problem is, the code in my snippet works as expected.

Comment: @Titus there is still spaces to be exact i check it via f12 then this is what the spaces is it added whole tr with td same with the search it only display in hidden not none

Comment: When an element is `display: none` it will still be in the DOM but it will not be visible and it will not occupy any space. I cannot figure out what the problem is, if you can't resolve it, post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you'd do it using modern Javascript. Let me know if anything is unclear, so I can explain in detail.

As a sidenote: Every `tr` "knows" it's `td`s and has stored them in an `HTMLCollection` called `cells`.

```js
search2.addEventListener('input', () => {
  myTable.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => row.hidden = row.cells[1].innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(search2.value.toUpperCase()) === -1)
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="imageindent">
      <img src="img.jpg" border="1" style="border-color:#CCCCCC" />
    </td>

    <td class="gentext"> JOHN BRYAN SMITH <span class="textCapitalized"></span>
      <span class="textCapitalized">
        Gray<br />JohnSMith@gmail.com      <br />
      </span>
    </td>

    <td class="gentext"><span class="texblue">JUNIOR PRODUCER</span>/<br />EVENTS</td>
    <td width="120" class="title2">2114</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="imageindent">
      <img src="img.jpg" border="1" style="border-color:#CCCCCC" />
    </td>

    <td class="gentext"> JACK BRUCE <span class="textCapitalized"></span>
      <span class="textCapitalized">
        Gray<br />JackBruce@gmail.com      <br />
      </span>
    </td>

    <td class="gentext"><span class="texblue">JUNIOR PRODUCER</span>/<br />EVENTS</td>
    <td width="120" class="title2">2114</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input name="search" type="text" class="textsimple" id="search2" />
```

Comment: @x'tian What browser are you using, and what exactly is not working?

Comment: i am using chrome searching and displaying of searched employee is not working

Comment: @x'tian Please try again, I made some modifications so case is no longer relevant for matches (so an input of "jac" also matches "JAC").

Comment: I have managed to run your code. The reason why is not working before is that there is another <tr> for <hr></hr> tag i removed that tr and now it is working but the problem is the height of the page changed when searching for ex. there is only one employee in that search the page become shorter. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Changed this line `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];` to use index `[1]` since you need the second `td`. The index `[0]` referred to the first TD. I recommend to use some class selector to get the right `td` since that is more reliable when the table structure changes.

Also you use an id in one of your td's (`id="empname"`). I assume you can get multiple rows. If so you need to make sure this id is unique. It's better to not use id's in dynamic content but classes instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  console.log(filter);
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      console.log(txtValue);
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="imageindent">
      <img src="img.jpg" border="1" style="border-color:#CCCCCC" />
    </td>

    <td class="gentext" id="empname"> JOHN BRYAN SMITH <span class="textCapitalized"></span>
      <span class="textCapitalized">
        Gray<br />JohnSMith@gmail.com      <br />
      </span>
    </td>

    <td class="gentext"><span class="texblue">JUNIOR PRODUCER</span>/<br />EVENTS</td>
    <td width="120" class="title2">2114</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input name="search" type="text" class="textsimple" id="search2" onkeyup="myFunction()" />
```